# You May need an appropriate loader to handle this file type error when using React UseState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Rightbar.jsx code snippet:

```
import "./rightbar.css"
import {Users} from "../../dummyData"
import Online from "../online/Online";
import { useEffect, useState, useContext } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { AuthContext } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Add, Remove } from "@material-ui/icons";

export default function Rightbar({ user }) {
  const PF = process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_FOLDER;
  const [subscriptions, setSubscriptions] = useState([]);
  const { user: currentUser, dispatch } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [followed, setFollowed] = useState(
    currentUser.followings.includes(user?.id)
  );
```

Error:
[image: error]

I've seen similar issues on here and have tried various solutions with installing file-loader and creating a webpack.config.js file. Although none of the solutions have seemed to work. I'm using npm instead of yarn. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I feel like the code snippet that is included in the error isn't correct (e.g. starting with `dispatch`). My guess is you don't have a loader for `.css` files. What happens if you remove `import "./rightbar.css"`?

Comment: Have you tried using [babel-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader)? I guess webpack doesn't understand optional chaining.

Comment: @romellem I believe it is since when I do const [followed, setFollowed] = useState(false); for instance, the code is able to compile

Comment: As @luscstandswithUkraine mentioned, actually probably the reason is your webpack doesn't understand the [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Try `user && user.id` instead of `user?.id`, or use [`babel-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-loader).